# How to return a result when for loop does not generate any result

Tags: python, for-loop

HI I am trying to compare a word to the words data and checking whether the input word is a palindrome. For example, drawer is a palindrome, as its reverse reward is also a true word.

I have the following code-

```
words = sorted({line.strip().lower() for line in open('words.txt', 'r')})
# words is a standard English dictionary

def signature(word):
    return ''.join(reversed(word))
def find_palindrom(myword):
    mysig = signature(myword)
    
    for word in words:
        if mysig == word:
            print(myword)
            print(mysig)
            print("It is a palindrome")
```

So, find_palindrome(drawer) will give the following output-
drawer
reward
It is a palindrome

However, if I check find_palindrome(post), it will not output anything as tsop is not a valid word. How, can I update the code so that if the word (like post) is not a palindrome, it gives an output-

```
post
tsop
Not a palindrome
```

Comment: How are we supposed to run this without your file? [mre]

Comment: An important issue of nomenclature: `print` is not "returning" anything -- it is just printing. Getting your head around the difference is an important early step in learning to program.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical use of the `else` on a loop.  See any mid-level tutorial on looping for details.

```
for word in words:
    if mysig == word:
        print(myword)
        print(mysig)
        print("It is a palindrome")
        break
else:
    print(myword)
    print(mysig)
    print("It is NOT a palindrome")
```

Note the careful indentation: `else` matches the `for`, *not* the `if`

Alternately, you simply set a flag:

```
is_palindrome = False

for word in words:
    if mysig == word:
        is_palindrome = True
        break

# Do your printing here; test the flag to choose the last line of output.
```

Comment: Indeed it is, but the whole loop is unnecessary in the first place - `if mysig in words:`

Comment: Yup ... but there's a very small limit to the amount of tutorial I will do in an answer.  :-)